# Convert nanoseconds timestamp to JavaScript Date()

Tags: javascript-date

I have a log with timestamps like, for example, `1686184163560519943`. [www.unixtimestamp.com](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) says they're nanoseconds. I want to convert these to [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then to `toLocaleTimeString()`.

`Date()` does not like this input and throws `Invalid Date`.

The prior people of the internet all seem to interested in getting *to* nanoseconds, not *from* them as I am.

Part of the problem, I think, is that when you convert it out of string form, what holds it is `BigInt`, and Date() doesn't want to take a BigInt.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70748467/timestampnanos-to-date-and-time-in-react-js) - divide your nanoseconds by 1000000 to get milliseconds and then it can be used in the `Date()` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` constructor accepts numbers as milliseconds, since your timestamp is in nanoseconds you can divide your number by 1000000 to do the conversion

```
new Date(1686184163560519943 / 1000000);
```

It returns the exact same date as [unixtimestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) does when given your number in nanoseconds